# Index out of rangeエラーが出ます

Tags: swift3

swift初心者です。csvファイルからコンマ区切りで配列に格納したものを、for文を使い２次元配列に格納したいのですが、レンジエラーが出て困っています。２次元配列の宣言の仕方がおかしいのかもしれません...迷宮入りしてます、どなたかご指摘お願いします。

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func loadDat(){
        var data:[[String]] = [[]]
        do {
            let csvPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data0112", ofType: "csv")
            let csvData = try String(contentsOfFile:csvPath!, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)
            let dataList = csvData.components(separatedBy:",")
            let a:Int = 31
            var b:Int = 0
            for i in 0...a{
               for j in 0...a{
                    data[i][j] = dataList[b]
                    b += 1
               }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    loadDat()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

[image: CSVファイルです]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Arrayの宣言時、要素数を決めて初期化する

まず、`Array`は、このような代入はできません。

```
var array = [1, 2, 3]
array[3] = 4
// fatal error: Index out of range
```

要素が3つしかないのに、4番目に代入しようとした、というエラーが出ます。

最初から、`Array`の要素数を決められる場合は、その要素数で、`Array`を初期化します。

```
var array = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 4)
// [0, 0, 0, 0]

var data = [[String]](repeating: [String](repeating: "", count: 32), count: 32)
```

32×32の二次元配列`data`を初期化するには、上のように、初期化も多重にします。
`Array`の要素数が当初不定の場合、`append`メソッドを使って、`Array`に要素を追加していきます。

```
var array: [Int] = []
array.append(100)
array.append(200)
// [100, 200]
```

---

#### 単純ミスで、プログラムをクラッシュさせない

配列`data`の初期化が解決したら、つぎに繰り返し文を見直します。現状では、配列`dataList`の要素数が、32×32よりひとつでも不足すると、やはり「Out of range」でクラッシュしてしまいます。繰り返しの回数を、`dataList.count`で終わらせることを考えます。

```
let number = 32
var data = [[String]](repeating: [String](repeating: "", count: number), count: number)

if let csvUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data0112", withExtension: "csv") {
    do {
        let csvData = try String(contentsOf: csvUrl)
        let dataList = csvData.components(separatedBy: ",")
        if dataList.count > number * number {
            // 要素数が、32×32を超える場合、なにかする。
            return
        }
        for (n, item) in dataList.enumerated() {
            data[n / number][n % number] = item
        }
    } catch {
        fatalError("Not found CSV files")
    }
}
```

`Array`のメソッド`enumerated()`について：これは、インデックスと配列の要素からなるTupleの配列を返します。`for i in 0..<dataList.count`と書くより、すこしスマートな記述ができます。